# Open AI Embeddings

Tags: python, openai-api, embedding, langchain

```
import openai
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model_name="ada")

query_result = embeddings.embed_query("Hello world")
len(query_result)
```

### When compiling the above code it gives the following error:

```
> ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-60-3e1d76e373bd> in <cell line: 4>()
>       2 from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
>       3 
> ----> 4 embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model_name="ada")
>       5 
>       6 query_result = embeddings.embed_query("Hello world")
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()
> 
> ValidationError: 1 validation error for OpenAIEmbeddings model_name  
> extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

I have tried using this :-

```
import os
from openai_embed import OpenAIEmbeddings

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "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"
api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=api_key)

query_result = embeddings.embed_query("Hello world")
print(len(query_result))
```

But the error is not fixing

Answer (score 2):

There is no `model_name` parameter. The parameter used to control which model to use is called `deployment`, not `model_name`. Additionally, there is no model called `ada`. You probably meant `text-embedding-ada-002`, which is the default model for langchain. If you're satisfied with that, you don't need to specify which model you want.

Here's an example of how to use `text-embedding-ada-002`.

```
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-xxxx"

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

print(embeddings.embed_query("Hello world"))
```

Here's an example of how to use a non-default model.

```py
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-xxxx"

# Use old version of Ada. You probably want V2 rather than this.
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment="text-similarity-ada-001")

print(embeddings.embed_query("Hello world"))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is embeddings

```
embeddings=OpenAIEmbeddings()
```

if you print `embeddings`:

```
OpenAIEmbeddings(client=<class 'openai.api_resources.embedding.Embedding'>, 
    model='text-embedding-ada-002', 
    deployment='text-embedding-ada-002', 
    openai_api_version='', 
    openai_api_base='',
    openai_api_type='', 
    openai_proxy='', 
    embedding_ctx_length=8191, 
    openai_api_key='sk-xxxxxx', 
    openai_organization='', 
    allowed_special=set(), 
    disallowed_special='all', 
    chunk_size=1000, max_retries=6, 
    request_timeout=None, headers=None, 
    tiktoken_model_name=None, 
    show_progress_bar=False, 
    model_kwargs={})
```

As you see it has `model` kwarg whose default value is `text-embedding-ada-002`. `model_name` kwarg is used in `HuggingFaceEmbeddings`. That is why you might be confused. `OpenAIEmbeddings` might cost you if you do not have trial but `HuggingFaceEmbeddings` is free.

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
# the choice of an embedding model depends on the specific NLP task
# you might need to use a different model 
embeddings=HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
```